# Laravel validation - required only when two conditions are true

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I want *purchaser_first_name* and *purchaser_last_name* to be required only when the value of gift input in the request is true and the value of authenticated input is false.

What I have tried so far:

```
  public function rules()
    {        
        return [
            'gift' => 'required',
             'authenticated'=>required,
             'purchaser_first_name' => 'required_if:gift,true,required_if:authenticated,false',
             'purchaser_last_name' => 'required_if:gift,true,required_if:authenticated,false',

        ];
    }
```

This approach turns out to use OR operator instead I want the AND operator.

Comment: you are not applying two `required_if`s there, you are only using one ... you have to use a `|` to distinguish that you are using another one as `required_if` takes a variable amount of arguments

Comment: This solves half of the problem because there are other scenarios. For instance, the rule should not be applied when authenticated is true. The way that you suggested it the validator will fire even in the cases when authenticated is false

Comment: i wasn't suggesting you do anything, i was fixing your incorrect usage of the syntax of rules, good luck

Comment: @PetroBianka did you check my solution? Or should I delete it?

Comment: @mare96 I just marked it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
'purchaser_first_name' => Rule::requiredIf(function () use ($request) {
    return $request->input('gift') && !$request->input('authenticated');
}),
```

In the function, you can set your logic. I'm not sure what you need for real, but it's good for a start.

Also, check [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-required-if) for more info about that.

Comment: I just had to use the request() helper method instead of $request to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your validation code as below :

```
return [
    'gift' => 'required',
    'authenticated'=>'required',
    'purchaser_first_name' => 'required_if:gift,true|required_if:authenticated,false',
    'purchaser_last_name' => 'required_if:gift,true|required_if:authenticated,false',
];
```

Comment: This solves half of the problem because there are other scenarios. For instance, the rule should not be applied when authenticated is true. The way that you suggested it the validator will fire even in the cases when authenticated is false.